# Confusion with Salesforce's Org-Wide Defaults

Tags: security, salesforce, force.com

I was going through the workbook for Salesforce. As per the work book below is the permission required.[image]

Now if I follow the rule to identify the Org-Wide Defaults, then for the object "Job Postings", the most restrictive user is "Hiring Manager" and the sharing model should be "Private". But in the book, it is mentioned that the sharing model should be "Public Read-Only".

I am kind of confused here. Can anyone please help me to understand this?

The workbook that I am referring is: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try cross-posting such questions to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com as it's more likely to attract attention of experienced Administrators.

(I'll add direct links as it's bit tricky to find this info)

[Hiring Manager's requirements](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/Content/adg_securing_data_perm_hiring_manager.htm), [Decision tree and summary](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/Content/adg_securing_data_org_wide_defaults_app.htm)

I think you're right, they shouldn't have that asterisk next to the "Read", only next to "Create" & "Edit". Logic dictates that if he'll not be able to see certain records, he could try to create duplicates & waste company money. Or maybe they tried to indicate that to have the "Edit" right you need to have "Read"...

---

Having said that - it's a bit of a moot point anyway.

The Entity Relationship Diagram from [Putting it all together](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/Content/adg_relationships_put_all_together.htm) indicates that it's a junction object, child of 2 masters. This means you effectively lose OWD on that object, it becomes "Controlled by Parent" (you can still slap sharing rules on it). You can try editing OWD in your own org if you have some master-details in there.